# Electric speed controller (ESC) interruption with FET

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller, fet

I would like to develop power distribution board for quadcopters. One of the task of this board is to interrupt power from battery going to ESC when the copter sleeps. The battery will never unplugged from this board.

There are 4x 40 A ESCs, so theoretically the maximum current will about 150 - 200 A. But probably it will use much less, the hovering amperage is about 20 - 30 A. Moreover, the battery will provide power only for some minutes (~5000 mAh).

I choosed two NFETs ([NVMTS0D4N04CL](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NVMTS0D4N04CL-D.PDF)) with Rds = 0.3 mohm, the maximum dissipation will be 5-6 W. Probably these FETs do it without heatsink. The size, weight and reliability are extremely important.

In the default state the FETs are pulled high with resistor (in case of program or microprocessor failure).

I designed two solutions:
**SOLUTION A:** The FETs are controlled by  VOM617A optocoupler with 2N7002-7. With these elements the two FETs are pulled low and turn off when the NFET_EN is high.

**SOLUTION B:** The two FETs are turned off with CPC1117N solid state relay when the NFET_EN is high.

In both cases the purpose of the  zener diode is limiting the voltage going to gate when the circuit is powered from more than 20V (5S or 6S battery). Each FETs has one flyback D1 and D2 diode.

**My questions:**
Do both circuits work?
Which one is better solution?
Is there any difference in reliability of two circuits?
Are diodes D1 and D2 required? I guess the ESC already has many of these.
Is there anything that can I improve in this circuit?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why use the opto coupler and ditto the SSR?

Comment: You have to be careful about having a ground return path through the PWM or I2C cable on the ESC, while PFETs typically have highest RdsOn, it seems like high side switching would be safer.  If you have opto-isolated ESCs this won't be an issue.